# Consulta de datos en Firestore (Firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, sql, firebase, aplicación-web

Quiero realizar una consulta en mi app web, esta está conectada a Cloud Firestore (Firebase), agregué una caja de texto con el id buscar_cliente, necesito que el nombre que escriba el usuario lo despliegue en mi tabla HTML solamente, tengo este código:

HTML:

```
        <h3>Buscar cliente:</h3>
        <center><input type="text" id="buscar_cliente" placeholder="Nombre del cliente" class="form-control my-2"></center>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="botonbuscar" onclick="buscar()">Buscar cliente</button>
        <br><br>-->
        <br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hora</th>
                    <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
                    <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                    <th scope="col">Editar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tabla">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

JS:

```
function buscar() {
    document.getElementById('buscar_cliente').value = nombre;
    var tabla = document.getElementById('tabla');
    db.collection("citas_registradas").where("nombre", "==", "buscar_cliente").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        tabla.innerHTML = '';
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().nombre}`);
            tabla.innerHTML += ` 
        <tr>
        <td>${doc.data().nombre}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().fecha}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().hora}</td>
        <td>${doc.data().telefono}</td>
        <td><button class="btn-danger" onclick="eliminar('${doc.id}')">Eliminar</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn-warning" onclick="editar('${doc.id}','${doc.data().nombre}','${doc.data().fecha}','${doc.data().hora}','${doc.data().telefono}')">Editar</button></td>
        </tr>`
        });
    });
}
```

Pero no me muestra nada, y si cambio el valor `"buscar_cliente"` en mi JS y pongo por ejemplo "Daniel Rivas" si busca, ¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el valor de la caja de texto tiene que ser de la siguiente forma:

```
var nombre_cliente = document.getElementById("buscar_cliente").value;
```

Y luego utilizar la variable para hacer tu consulta a firebase:

```
db.collection("citas_registradas").where("nombre", "==", nombre_cliente).onSnapshot(...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la respuesta es correcta.